# How to sync pthreads inside epoll?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, epoll

I'm still trying to implement inter-thread communication, and I don't understand how to make threads read a shared chunk of data when it is available. The problem is: I'm listening to a few sockets inside epoll in each thread, and if I receive information form one I need to inform other threads to read it.

I have tried eventfd with EFD_SEMAPHORE, but it doesn't suit because there's one thread that reads all data from it ahead of everybody. I cannot find a use for posix semaphores or condition variables because they can hardly be used with epoll.

Is there any way to implement such a synchronization easily?

UPDATE:

```
int k = epoll_wait(epollfd, n, events);
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    int fd = events[i].data.fd;
    if (fd == eventfd) {
        if (eventfd_read(eventfd, ..) != -1)
            /* for each socket on this thread send latest_message to it */
    }
    else {
        latest_message = read_message(fd);
        eventfd_write(eventfd, 1)
    }
}
```

this is the example of what I'm trying to do, assuming recvs are rare.
Actually, I thought about better idea, why do I have to bind sockets to thread when I can have a list of all sockets and just let the fastest threads send the messages, increasing something like last_reciever variable on message structure.

Comment: Check this [How to Use C Mutex Lock Examples for Linux Thread Synchronization](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/?refcom).

Comment: I still don't get it, I don't need to lock the thread because it has other things to do with epoll, like reading from inet sockets and pipes, but mutexes either block the thread or don't unblock epoll_wait, which is needed. Also, when I unlock the mutex, there's still data in eventfd, and the same thread may lock the mutex again and again while polling.

Comment: `eventfd` is the right way to go. If it doesn't work for you, please show a minimum example and we can help you debug.